# How to get website to remember choices to be inputed in to a form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cookies

I'm looking for a way to create a page with items on it where each item has a button which can be clicked to "like" or "choose" the item. The website would then remember the choices and input them to a form on another page. Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: u can use session for it

Comment: Using PHP Sessions You can do.

Comment: excluding sessions, you can use local storage.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance if we are talking about a registered user, i would create fields in the database for the user's input and store its value everytime he makes a selection. Then its only a matter of putting those values wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have several choices. If it is persistent data, I'd suggest a database like MySQL. If you don't have access to that, then Google for "flat file database" and you'll find some great ideas.

If the data is persistent, but not a big deal if it gets deleted or spoofed, you can use cookies.

If the data is fleeting (it goes away at the end of the visit), then use sessions.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do is storing each result in a SESSION and reusing it in other form.